# Find values in a list that are not in others lists

Tags: python, list

Let's take these sample lists :

```
L_main = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
L1 = [1,7,3,12]
L2 = [0,2,51,5,9]
L3 = [3,2,8]
```

I would like to create a list which contains the values of L_main that are neither in L1, nor in L2, nor in L3. The following code does the job, but it is **really slow** with big lists :

```
[i for i in L_main if i not in L1 and i not in L2 and i not in L3]
```

Do you know please a more efficient way ?
Expected result :

```
[4,6]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `set` differences between `L_main` and the rest of your lists concatentated together:

```
>>> list(set(L_main).difference(L1+L2+L3))
[4, 6]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can compute the `set.difference` of all the latter lists from the first one.

```
>>> set(L_main).difference(L1,L2,L3)
{4, 6}
```

Answer (score 0):

`.difference` is probably better, but worth noting that you can subtract sets as well.

```
set(L_main)-set(L1+L2+L3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a simple for can be quicker in this case.

```
final_list = []
for num in L_main:
    if num not in L1 and num not in L2 and num not in L3:
         final_list.append(num)
```

I know that semantically it is the same of the example in your question, but you can use `time.time()` to measure the time for big lists.

You can also change the `.append()` and use the `+=` operator, it is also quicker:

```
final_list = []
for num in L_main:
    if num not in L1 and num not in L2 and num not in L3:
         final_list += [num]
```

Cheers.

EDIT: I also like a lot the set differences proposed, my answer is just in case you do not want to change the structure.

Answer (score 0):

Change the list to sets and change your code.

```
l = set.union(set(l1),set(l2), set(l3))
list(set(L_main)-l)
```

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

Time trials on a modest laptop favour

```
list(set(L_main).difference(L1,L2,L3))
```

which for large lists offers dramatic improvements over a naive list comprehension or its `for` loop near-equivalent.

**Detail**

Surprisingly enough using a dict seems to hold its own (but is not good enough to justify switching from a good `set` implementation):

```
from itertools import chain
excludes = dict((n,None) for n in chain(L1, L2, L3))
[n for n in L_main if n not in excludes]
```

A defaultdict can also be used but the modification is probably pointless (included in the analysis below for posterity).

Some horse races on a modest laptop using 3.9 (CPython):

Original sample data (unsurprisingly doesn't tell us much):

```
%%timeit #used for all of these, not shown later
# OP starting solution
i for i in L_main if i not in L1 and i not in L2 and i not in L3] # is slow for big lists
3.82 µs ± 22.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

# Set v1
list(set(L_main).difference(L1+L2+L3))
3.75 µs ± 113 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

# Set v2
list(set(L_main).difference(L1,L2,L3))
3.57 µs ± 142 ns

# Set v3
list(set(L_main)-set(L1+L2+L3))
3.57 µs ± 48.6 ns

# Set v4
l = set.union(set(L1),set(L2), set(L3))
list(set(L_main)-l)
5.06 µs ± 176 ns

# For loop
final_list = []
for num in L_main:
    if num not in L1 and num not in L2 and num not in L3:
         final_list += [num]
final_list
3.9 µs ± 98.1 ns

# Dict v1
excludes = dict((n,None) for n in chain(L1, L2, L3))
[n for n in L_main if n not in excludes]
9.09 µs ± 115 ns # worse here, but wait!

# Dict v2 (defaultdict)
excludes = defaultdict(None, ((n, None) for n in chain(L1, L2, L3)))
[n for n in L_main if n not in excludes]
12.9 µs ± 72.5 ns
```

Now on a moderately large set, i.e.

```
from random import randint
L_main = range(10000)
L1 = [randint(900, 20000) for _ in range(1000)]
L2 = [randint(900, 20000) for _ in range(2000)]
L3 = [randint(900, 20000) for _ in range(3000)]
len(L_main), len(L1), len(L2), len(L3)
(10000, 1000, 2000, 3000)
```

Results from slowest to fastest:

```
2200ms OP Starting solution
2160ms For loop
7.7ms Set v3 (+/- .7ms) 
5.8ms Set v4 (+/- .6ms)
5.1ms Dict v1 (+/- .2ms)
5.0ms Dict v2 (+/- .2ms) # Not significantly different from v1
4.4ms Set v1 (+/- .6ms)
3.7ms Set v2 (+/- .3ms)
```

Finally, with an additional ~9x upsize in the input lists, i.e.

```
from random import randint
L_main = range(50000)
L1 = [randint(900, 80000) for _ in range(9000)]
L2 = [randint(900, 80000) for _ in range(15000)]
L3 = [randint(900, 80000) for _ in range(30000)]
len(L_main), len(L1), len(L2), len(L3)
(50000, 9000, 15000, 30000)
```

We have:

```
SKIP  OP Starting solution
SKIP  For loop
58ms Set v4 (+/- 1ms)
53ms Dict v2 (+/- 3ms) # Not significantly diff from v1
51ms Dict v1 (+/- 3ms)
50ms Set v3 (+/- 1ms) 
42ms Set v1 (+/- 2ms)
38ms Set v2 (+/- 1ms) # Enough of an edge to be statistically significant
```